# Что значит функция code

Tags: функции, kotlin, intellij-idea, методы

Не так давно начал изучать Kotlin и возник вопрос что делает функция(а может это и не функция) **code** и почему Идея зачеркивает **c.toInt()** и предлагает заменить на **c.code**

---

```
for(c in 'A'..'F'){
            val binary = Integer.toBinaryString(c.code)
```

---

---

```
for(c in 'A'..'F'){
        val binary = Integer.toBinaryString(c.toInt())
```

---

помогите)

Answer (score 0):

Если навести курсор, то во всплывающей подсказке будет написано почему. А именно -  функция `char.toInt()` считается устаревшей и теперь нужно использовать `char.code`

[Ссылка на документацию](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-char/to-int.html).